# Как закачать/импортировать библиотеку в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, library

Я хочу скачать библиотеку, я вроде скачал через пип но кз как её импортировать. В пайчарм ворчит на отсутствие setup.py, пробовал в каталог положить основной файл, не работает

Comment: а что по этому поводу говорит учебник?

Comment: @Эникейщик, смотря какой, учебник по библиотеке просто говорит про команду и предоставляет код который не работает в связи с отсутствием модуля, а учебник по питону не говорил про то как качать библиотеки

Comment: после каких действий ворчит? какой такой основной файл? в какой каталог?

Comment: после кнопки add package from disk, основной файл - файл у которого название библиотеки, каталог с файлами где мне надо эта библиотека

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы закачать библиотеку используется консольная команда "pip install XXX" (XXX-библиотека). А импортируется она внутри вашего кода, обычно пишут вначале файла "import XXX".

Comment: в какой консоли? Если в питоновской, то SyntaxError, а если Windows PowerShell, то пишет что уже скачано, а в проекте когда копирую код с обучалки говорит что такой модуль не найден

Comment: это означает что в powershell и пайчармы разные питоны. В одном месте установил, в другом нет.

Comment: ну в таком случае, как сделать так что бы был 1 и тот же?

Comment: Возможно, что питоны одинаковые. Но если создается виртуальное окружение, то библиотеки, которые установлены через Windows PowerShell все равно надо переустановить с помощью pip install ... То есть, в PyCharm открываете терминал и пишите команду. И не надо изобретать велосипед.

Comment: И еще проверить установлен ли интерпритатор в PyCharm.  Окройте PyCharm - File - Settings - Python Interpreter.

Comment: @Vasilijs у меня в пайчарм есть путь этих натроек до Python Interpreter, а Python Interpreter уже нет такого

Comment: @Евгений у меня в терминале питона если написать такую команду, то выйдет SyntaxError, а в повершелл говорит что уже скачано, а по факту - нет. (Всё это в пайчарм, но так же и вне пайчарм)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал вам не мучиться, а удалить питон, удалить пайчарм и установить все правильно, хотя бы вот по этой инструкции: https://webformyself.com/kak-ustanovit-python-na-windows-pycharm-ide/

Comment: Я попробую ваш совет

Comment: @Евгений Спасибо, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, установлено ли у вас виртуальное окружение. То есть, в левом верхнем углу поищите папку venv. Если да, то вам нужно в самом PyCharm открыть терминал и установить в нем ту библиотеку, которая вам нужна, даже если вы ее  устанавливали до этого через PowerShell или CMD.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет такой папки

Comment: Можно и без нее. Но в теории, тогда то, что установлено через PowerShell должно подхватываться автоматом. Если у вас, конечно, указан системный интерпретатор.

Comment: у меня наверное местный интерпретатор тк он даже не на c:/ и название там такое же как название проекта